# How can vertical force due to gravity vary in a column?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

Non-physicist asking.

Suppose I have a tall building or column. The downward pressure on the walls near the foundations is intuitively greater than at the top of the building. Yet according to Newton, at every point, a particle of wall should experience equal and opposite up/down forces or it would start moving.

If at every point, the force from above exactly equals the force from below, why does the whole building not experience the same level of compression?

f1 = f2 and f2 = f3 implies f1 = f3, so all forces should be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If at every point, the force from above exactly equals the force from below ...

The internal forces (stresses) acting from above and below on each part of the column are *not* equal. You have to take into account any external forces on the column - in particular, you need to include the weight of each part of the column. Suppose we take a small slice of the column of height $\delta h$ at a height $h$ above the ground. If the cross-sectional area of the column is $A$, and its density is $\rho$ (and, to keep things simple, we will assume that $A$ and $\rho$ are constant) then the mass of the slice is $\rho A \delta h$, and so its weight is $\rho A g \delta h$. So the stress at height $h$ will be greater than the stress at height $h + \delta h$ by an amount equal to the weight of the slice, which is $\rho A g \delta h$. If the column has height $H$ and we know the stress at the top of the column is $0$ then the stress at the bottom of the column is

$\int_{h=0}^H \rho A g \delta h = \rho AHg = Mg$

where $M = \rho A H$ is the mass of the whole column.